# RegEx Replace Automatic SQL code creator

Tags: r, regex

I built a script in `R` that automatically create a very long and complex SQL query to create a view over similar tables of 5 databases.

Of course there were integration issues to solve. The only one remaining to make this happen is the problem I am going to present you now.

Considering one very long string like

```
'"/*NOTES*/", "/*TABLE_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*/", "OTHER_COLUMNS",'
```

My objective is to replace

- this string `'"/*'` with this string `'/*'`
- this string `'*/",'` with this string `'*/'`

I tried with:

```
gsub('"/*', '/*', '"/*NOTES*/", "/*TABLE_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*/", "OTHER_COLUMNS",')
```

but it returns the string

```
'/**NOTES*//*, /**TABLE_ID*//*, /**TABLE_SUB_ID*//*, /**TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*//*, /*OTHER_COLUMNS/*,'
```

whereas **my expected output** is the following string:

```
'/*NOTES*/ /*TABLE_ID*/ /*TABLE_SUB_ID*/ /*TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*/ "OTHER_COLUMNS",'
```

#### Note the * is not escaped but it represents start (`/*`) and end (`*/`) of comments when the string will be run by a SQL compiler

Comment: You need to escape the asterisk in your `gsub` pattern, ala `'"/\\*'`. Perhaps `gsub('"?(/\\*|\\*/)"?', '\\1', vec)`?

Comment: master commander!!! why do I have to double-escape it? Because I tried single escale \ but it returned the following error: Error: '\*' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'"/\*". So I thought it was the wrong path to find the solution

Comment: In R, very few characters allow a single-backslash. To escape things, you nearly always require two backslashes. The reason you have to escape it at all is that in regexes, the asterisk says *"0 or more of the preceding character/class"*, so `'"/*'` translates into *"a double-quote followed by zero or more slashes"*, not what you need.

Comment: Thank you, if you write that in a answer I can accept it and close the question

Comment: Therefore, to be sure I should always double-escape everything or is there any risk in this approach?

Comment: In R, this is called "escaping" (and in R you escape with two backslashes). In regexes, several characters have special meaning, including `[`, `]`, `*`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `^`, `$`, and `|`. I might have missed one or two, but those need to be escaped if you are trying to match the literal character. If you aren't familiar with regular expressions ... I've got news for you ... https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: what is this website with a very suspicious link?

Comment: XKCD is *"a webcomic of romance, sarcasm, math, and language"* (artist's words), I've referenced it a few times for various programming-y issues such as regexes and [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/). That specific image is a link suggesting the complexity of regular expressions: "... I got 99 problems, so I used regular expressions ... now I have 100 problems". The point is that regexes are powerful yet difficult to do complex things correctly. My apologies for the random link :-)

Comment: So I am not the only one thinking regex are like dark magic hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping regexes requires two backslashes, so the following will get you what you want:

```
gsub('"?(/\\*|\\*/)"?', '\\1', '"/*NOTES*/", "/*TABLE_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_ID*/", "/*TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*/", "OTHER_COLUMNS",')
# [1] "/*NOTES*/, /*TABLE_ID*/, /*TABLE_SUB_ID*/, /*TABLE_SUB_SUB_ID*/, \"OTHER_COLUMNS\","
```

FYI, double-backslashes are required for most, but the following are legitimate single-backslash special characters:

```
'\a\b\f\n\r\t\v'
# [1] "\a\b\f\n\r\t\v"
'\u0101' # unicode, numbers are variable
# [1] "a"
'\x0A'   # hex, hex-numbers are variable
# [1] "\n"
```

Perhaps there are more, I didn't find the authoritative list though I'm sure it's in there somewhere.